# PowerShell Parsing error?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I am getting powershell parsing error. My script is as:

> $ServerName=".\SQL"
>
> $ScriptLoc=$pwd
>
> echo $pwd
>
> $DrScript=$(scriptLoc)\main_file.sql
>
> echo $DrScript

After executing the script I am getting:

> Unexpected token '\main_file.sql' in expression or statement. At
>   D:\Powershell-MyScripts\powerfile.ps1:8 char:45
>   + $DrScript=$(scriptLoc)\main_file.sql  <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (\main_file.sql:String) [], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

please help me to get over it.

PS: I am converting the batch script to Powershell script so I facing such error. Please advise if there is good tutorial which help me to get over this.

Answer (score 2):

You're building the string in `$DrScript=$(scriptLoc)\main_file.sql` incorrectly. To construct that string, wrap the variable and the constant in double quotes; the variable will be expanded automatically.

```
$DrScript="$scriptLoc\main_file.sql"
```

Wrapping the variable in parens is only necessary if it's an object whose property you need to access directly within a quoted string. For example:

```
$DrScript="$($scriptLoc.propertyname)\main_file.sql"
```

But you don't need that here.

Also, PowerShell style note: `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`. Aliases should be reserved for the command line; when you're writing a reusable script, use the full cmdlet name. Aliases can be redefined (or removed entirely) in another user's environment, so creating a dependency upon one that you aren't defining in your script can cause failure.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around your path. Also need to ensure that you have your variable $scriptLoc named properly with a dollar sign at the beginning.

```
$DrScript="$($scriptLoc)\main_file.sql"
```